# Not able to trace a service from Jaeger UI using spring-boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, jaeger

Unable to trace a services for springboot application on Jaeger UI(localhost:16686/search). Here I am able to run an application successfully, but unable to get a services in jaeger ui(Except defalut one jaeger-query).

I used docker cmd to start the jaeger service,

```
docker run --rm -it --network=host jaegertracing/all-in-one
```

Open the Jaeger UI on http://localhost:16686/search

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.uber.jaeger.Configuration;
import com.uber.jaeger.samplers.ProbabilisticSampler;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoOpentracing1Application {


@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    return restTemplateBuilder.build();
}

@Bean
public io.opentracing.Tracer jaegerTracer() {
    return new Configuration("spring-boot", new Configuration.SamplerConfiguration(ProbabilisticSampler.TYPE, 1),
            new Configuration.ReporterConfiguration())
            .getTracer();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoOpentracing1Application.class, args);
}
```

}

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@RequestMapping("/hello")
public String hello() {
    return "Hello from Spring Boot!";
}

@RequestMapping("/chaining")
public String chaining() {
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8082/hello", String.class);
    return "Chaining + " + response.getBody();
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo_opentracing1</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo_opentracing1</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
        <artifactId>opentracing-spring-web-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.uber.jaeger</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaeger-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.18.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Pa0D.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTFVj.png)

Github repository with demo: https://github.com/pavolloffay/opentracing-java-examples.
Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your Jaeger collector is not accessible from outside docker network host as you specified in your docker command. This would only work if your spring boot application is deployed on the host network too.
Try to run Jaeger as follows:

```
docker run -d --name jaeger \
  -e COLLECTOR_ZIPKIN_HTTP_PORT=9411 \
  -p 5775:5775/udp \
  -p 6831:6831/udp \
  -p 6832:6832/udp \
  -p 5778:5778 \
  -p 16686:16686 \
  -p 14268:14268 \
  -p 14250:14250 \
  -p 9411:9411 \
  jaegertracing/all-in-one:1.17
```

It should trigger.